# Why does NumPy array not update original array using predictor

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am learning NumPy (and Python) and working through some exercises regarding arrays. I had a question that came up that I could not comprehend. I understand that the following code should update the original array that `b` is pointed to. The code is as follows.

```
a = np.zeros((4,5))
b = a[1:3,0:3]
b = b + 100
print('a = ', a)
print('b = ', b)
```

The output is:

```
a =  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
b =  [[100. 100. 100.]
 [100. 100. 100.]]
```

Why does `a` not update along with `b`? I understand that a pointer object should update the original with edits. I'm assuming it is due to the syntax that 100 is added to `b`. The code below updates, as I thought, with the original array changing. What is the difference?

```
a = np.zeros((4,5))
b = a[1:3,0:3]
b[0, 0] = 100
print('a = ', a)
```

Output:

```
a =  [[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [100.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Comment: `b + 100` creates a new array, it doesn't modify the array that `b` references. And assigning to `b` doesn't update the array in place, it changes `b` to point to the new array.

Comment: Oh ok. I should have checked the ID of the array. Would that be the general logic for any mathematical operation? i.e. if it was `b*5` or `b/5` would that also create a new array? That makes sense though. Thank you

Comment: Yes. In general, numpy operations don't modify the array in place.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. Is there any way I can select your response as the answer?

Comment: It's not an answer, it just explains why you're not getting what you want. I don't know enough numpy to show how to get your desired result.

Comment: `b(0,0]=...` modifies `b`.  `b= ...` assigns a (new) object to `b` (the variable, not the object that was asigned to `b`.  This isn't just `numpy`, it is basic python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not have pointers, at least not in the sense of other languages such as C.

What is happening here is that when you index an array, i.e. `a[1:3,0:3]`, you create a view of a part of the data in `a`.
[Numpy docs on what views are](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html)

In your first example, you then evaluate `b + 100`, which creates a new array.
This behavior is not changed by the fact that you assign the result to the same variable name `b`.

In your second example `b[0, 0] = 100`, you modify `b` in-place.
Since `b` is just a view of `a`, you also modify corresponding entries of `a`.

You could rewrite your first example to do `b += 100` instead, which again modifies `b` in-place and will also change `a`

Comment: What is the difference between b = b + 100 and b += 100? I thought those would be the same operation.

Comment: In principle, the two operations do not need to be related whatsoever.
A python object can decide what the two operations do, individually.

For consistency, the resulting value of b should be the same, but side-effects of the operation can be different.

Most operators have an in-place version (there is e.g. `*=` for multiplication)
and the effect depends on the type of object you are acting on.

This view-like behavior is specific to the object type being a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block, you are setting the value of `b` equal to what it was before + and adding 100 to all of its value.

```py
b = b + 100
```

In the second code block, you are setting the value of the number in the `[0, 0]` position equal to 100. Since `b` is just a pointer to `a`, it also modifies the value of `a`

```py
b[0, 0] = 100
```

The difference between the two is that in the first one you are cloning `b` then modify it (then assign it to `b`). Where in the second one, you do **not** clone it, and just modifies it.